# Print gif using java on a 4x6" paper

Tags: java, printing, gif, thermal-printer

What is the best way in Java to print a gif given as `byte[]` or `ByteArrayInputStream` on a paper with a size of 4x6 inches?

This:

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(new MediaSize(4, 6, Size2DSyntax.INCH));
aset.add(new Copies(1));
PrintService[] pservices =
PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, aset);

DocPrintJob printJob = pservices[0].createPrintJob();
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(sap.getGraphicImageBytes(), DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, null);
printJob.print(doc, aset);
```

does not work because the MediaSize is not a PrintRequestAttribute. This should be almost the same as in [Package javax.print Description](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem

```
PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
format.setOrientation(PageFormat.REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);

PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(OrientationRequested.REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
aset.add(MediaSizeName.JAPANESE_POSTCARD);

PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printerJob.setPrintable(new ImagePrintable(sap.getGraphicImage()));
printerJob.defaultPage(format);
printerJob.print(aset);
```

The trick was using japanese postcard as media size.

Comment: Voting this one up.  This got me out of a bind quickly for fixing some default paper size problems printing to a 4x6 thermal label printer in CUPS (Linux, Mac), thank you.