# Java printing API: java.lang.ClassCastException on custom media size

Tags: java

The following code throws java.lang.ClassCastException

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(new MediaSize(60,80,Size2DSyntax.MM));
```

I suspect I did line 2 incorrectly, but I cannot find detailed documentation for Java printing services. What is the proper way to define custom media size?

Comment: can you also include that `ClassCastException` here?

Comment: There is no content associated with this exception

Comment: Oh! I thought this exception message generally says `class1 cannot be cast to class2`.

Comment: It looks like MediaSize is not designed to specify custom paper size. I am doing it wrong. I am trying to write a printing service for POS printer.

Comment: `MediaSize` does look like a valid attribute. Did you try using `MediaSizeName.ISO_A4` (or something in those lines) for that last argument to specify the paper size?

Comment: I tried. Got the same exception, and there is no message comes with the exception.

Comment: would you be able to just print a bit more code? I suspect some catch statement is just eating away the exception message and printing the exception class name, I may be completely incorrect though!

Comment: It works with aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_B7); as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290937/print-gif-using-java-on-a-4x6-paper .But they didn't give a way to print on custom sized paper.

Comment: @Vikdor The exception is thrown this way. [see here](http://ideone.com/1u3VJ) [mirror](https://gist.github.com/3757552)

Comment: somehow that page doesn't open for me (times out) :(

Comment: Did someone find something about defining a custom MediaSize? I am totally stuck with the same exception and I don't find anything helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MediaSize` does not implement `PrintRequestAttribute`, hence the error.

Instead, I think, you need to use something like

```
aset.add(new MediaPrintableArea(5, 5, 50, 80, MediaPrintableArea.MM));
```

instead...

You can check out [MediaPrintableArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaPrintableArea.html) for me details.

Comment: I am maybe wrong but MediaPrintableArea is to tell which part of the selected MediaSize is printable, but not te define a custom MediaSize
Am I wrong?

Comment: @phyzalis AFAIK This is just about requesting information about printers capable of printing the specified area